# Parsing JSON from reddit JSON API

Tags: android, json, android-volley, reddit

When I request data from the reddit JSON API, I get the following in my **jsonRequestObject**:

```
[ ] https://www.reddit.com/.json 0x70eb7ea8 NORMAL null
```

This is the code I am using:

```java
public class RedditFront {
    private static String frontPageURL = "https://www.reddit.com/.json";
    private static String jsonResponse = "";


    public static void redditFrontAll(final Context context) throws JSONException {
        Log.d("REDDIT", "got here");

        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,
                frontPageURL, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                try {
                    JSONObject data = response.getJSONObject("data");
                    JSONArray children = data.getJSONArray("children");
                    for (int i = 0; i < children.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject topic = children.getJSONObject(i);

                        String author = topic.getString("author");
                        String imageUrl = topic.getString("thumbnail");
                        String postTime = topic.getString("created_utc");
                        String rScore = topic.getString("score");
                        String title = topic.getString("title");
                        Log.d("REDDIT_TITLE:", title);
                    }

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Toast.makeText(context,
                            "Error: " + e.getMessage(),
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

            }
        },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                        Toast.makeText(context,
                                error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
                });
        Log.d("JSON:", jsonResponse);
    }
}
```

I am not really sure about volley in general, so I followed a tutorial for this. The JSON code I thought was correct but I am not really sure. Would someone be able to help me out? Thanks

Comment: what's the problem? Do you just want confirmation whether you have done your parsing correctly or not

Comment: `Would someone be able to help me out?` with what? What is a problem?

Comment: With the Reddit API, you can plug in your request URL into a web browser and see the returned JSON in the browser window. Does that do anything for you?

Answer (score 0):

Plz add header like this in json request class

```
 @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
                headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
                return headers;
            }
```